# Leaflet and Mapbox: Buttons not working when added via Javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

Anyone know why that, when clicked, the buttons do not add or remove overlays from the map? [**Full PLNKR here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UPUCe5xTWyBVc4kkeRbf?p=preview)

The HTML

```
<div id="toggleButtons" style="display: none">
 <button id="add">Add Overlays</button>
 <button id="remove">Remove Overlays</button>
</div>
```

The Javascript

```
L.Control.GroupedLayers.include({
addOverlays: function () {
    for (var i in this._layers) {
        if (this._layers[i].overlay) {
            if (!this._map.hasLayer(this._layers[i].layer)) {
                this._map.addLayer(this._layers[i].layer);
            }
        }
    }
},
removeOverlays: function () {
    for (var i in this._layers) {
        if (this._layers[i].overlay) {
            if (this._map.hasLayer(this._layers[i].layer)) {
                this._map.removeLayer(this._layers[i].layer);
            }
        }
    }
 }
});

var control = new L.Control.GroupedLayers(ExampleData.Basemaps, {
'Landmarks': {
    'Cities': ExampleData.LayerGroups.cities,
    'Restaurants': ExampleData.LayerGroups.restaurants
},
'Random': {
    'Dogs': ExampleData.LayerGroups.dogs,
    'Cats': ExampleData.LayerGroups.cats
}
}).addTo(map);

L.DomEvent.addListener(L.DomUtil.get('add'), 'click', function () {
control.addOverlays();
});

L.DomEvent.addListener(L.DomUtil.get('remove'), 'click', function () {
control.removeOverlays();
});
```

And then I added the mapbox `legendControl.addLegend` method ([from the mapbox API documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-legend/))

```
map.legendControl.addLegend(document.getElementById('toggleButtons').innerHTML);
```

Although the buttons are shown in the map, their click properties are not working. Any clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not 'adding' the buttons with javascript, you're making a copy of them and placing the copy into the legendControl. The actual buttons with the eventhandlers are still present in the DOM but hidden because you've added `display: none` as inline style. What you want to do is select the buttons and remove them from the body:

```
var buttons = document.getElementById('toggleButtons');
document.body.removeChild(buttons);
```

Then you can add them to the legend and attach the eventhandlers:

```
var legendControl = L.mapbox.legendControl().addTo(map);

legendControl.addLegend(buttons.innerHTML);

L.DomEvent.addListener(L.DomUtil.get('add'), 'click', function () {
    control.addOverlays();
});

L.DomEvent.addListener(L.DomUtil.get('remove'), 'click', function () {
    control.removeOverlays();
});
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7pDkrZbS7Re1YshKZSLs?p=preview

PS. I'm quite baffled as to why you would abuse mapbox's legend control class to add two buttons. If you need a custom control you can just create one using leaflet's `L.Control` class. It spares you from loading the legend control class which you're not using, thus bloat.

EDIT: As promised in the comments below an example of rolling this solution into your own custom control. I'll explain to more throughout the comments in the code but the general idea is take the basic `L.Control` interface and adding the functionality and DOM generation to it:

```
// Create a new custom control class extended from L.Control
L.Control.Toggle = L.Control.extend({

    // Have some default options, you can also change/set
    // these when intializing the control
    options: {
        position: 'topright',
        addText: 'Add',
        removeText: 'Remove'
    },

    initialize: function (control, options) {
        // Add the options to the instance
        L.setOptions(this, options);
        // Add a reference to the layers in the layer control
        // which is added to the constructor upon intialization
        this._layers = control._layers;
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {
        // Create the container
        var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'control-overlaystoggle'),
            // Create add button with classname, append to container
            addButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'control-overlaystoggle-add', container),
            // Create remove button with classname, append to container
            removeButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'control-overlays-toggleremove', container);

        // Add texts from options to the buttons
        addButton.textContent = this.options.addText;
        removeButton.textContent = this.options.removeText;

        // Listen for click events on button, delegate to methods below
        L.DomEvent.addListener(addButton, 'click', this.addOverlays, this);
        L.DomEvent.addListener(removeButton, 'click', this.removeOverlays, this);

        // Make sure clicks don't bubble up to the map
        L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(container);

        // Return the container
        return container;
    },

    // Methods to add/remove extracted from the groupedLayerControl
    addOverlays: function () {
        for (var i in this._layers) {
            if (this._layers[i].overlay) {
                if (!this._map.hasLayer(this._layers[i].layer)) {
                    this._map.addLayer(this._layers[i].layer);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    removeOverlays: function () {
        for (var i in this._layers) {
            if (this._layers[i].overlay) {
                if (this._map.hasLayer(this._layers[i].layer)) {
                    this._map.removeLayer(this._layers[i].layer);
                }
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Now you can use your new control as follows:

```
// Create a new instance of your layer control and add it to the map
var layerControl = new L.Control.GroupedLayers(baselayers, overlays).addTo(map);

// Create a new instance of your toggle control
// set the layercontrol and options as parameters
// and add it to the map
var toggleControl = new L.Control.Toggle(layerControl, {
    position: 'bottomleft',
    addText: 'Add overlays',
    removeText: 'Remove overlays'
}).addTo(map);
```

I know, this is quick and dirty but it should give you a decent idea of what you can do with the `L.Control` class in general.

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7pDkrZbS7Re1YshKZSLs?p=preview

And here's the reference for `L.Control`: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control

Comment: Thanks so much for providing a plunker example. This made sense to me. As to why you are baffled that I would abuse mapbox's legend control class..it's because this is the method that makes sense to me...I'm a javascript newbie...still trying to learn as I go. Thanks.

Comment: Check back in a day or so, i'll edit my answer to include a `L.Control` example that will even make more sense. Short on time right now.

Comment: Thanks! I look forward to it. There's not much help elsewhere...and leaflet docs are kind of complex for the newbie.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense...but question: why do you have the 'container' parameter in these lines?
 
addButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'control-overlaystoggle-add', container),
            removeButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'control-overlays-toggleremove', container);

Comment: The third parameter of `L.DomUtil.create` is for the element the created element is supposed to be appended to. It puts the button element into the div element which was created before. `L.DomUtil.create`: "Creates an element with tagName, sets the className, and optionally appends it to container element." see: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#domutil-create

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks. Now, would I be using this same L.Control.extend method to create custom layers controls for my map UI? For example, accordion menus for layers,  offcanvas menus, etc.

Comment: Yes, it's what `L.Control` is intended for. All of Leaflet's controls, zoom, attribution, scale and layer are extended from it. If you need a control that's supposed to be on the canvas, use it. It takes care of positioning for you and gives you a nice class based start. I wouldn't use it for offcanvas controls though because the `addTo` and `remove` methods are `L.Map` specific and the position logic would be useless.

Comment: Am I able to put the groupedLayers plugin into a div so I can style it using getelementbyId?

Comment: Comments are meant for clarifying questions/answers not for asking a completely new question. If you've got a new question just post a new question. Others will see it too, so you'll be helped out a lot sooner/better then like this.

Comment: Thanks, I just added a new question in relation to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314753/leaflet-extending-custom-control-with-grouped-layers-control-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow delegation strategy here..

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click',   function(event) {
  if (event.target.id.toLowerCase() === 'add') {
    control.addOverlays();
  }
  if (event.target.id.toLowerCase() === 'remove') {
    control.removeOverlays();
  }
});
```