# Leaflet: Extending custom control with Grouped Layers Control plugin

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using a Leaflet plugin called [Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol](https://github.com/ismyrnow/Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol) and trying to figure out how to place this groupedlayercontrol plugin in an HTML div so I can better manage it. Code below and [PLNKR here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OqfFLtCdc8q5TaIER9ka?p=preview).

My hypothetical overlays object looks like this:

```
var map = new L.Map('mapbox', {
'center': [39.76185, -104.881105],
'zoom': 9,
'layers': [
    L.tileLayer('//{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'text here'
    })
]});

var pizza = L.marker([39.8443948439646, -104.97711181640625]).addTo(map);
var hamburger = L.marker([39.97291055131899, -105.08697509765625]).addTo(map);
var pie = L.marker([40.111688665595956, -104.776611328125]).addTo(map);

var overlaysOptions = {
      groupCheckboxes: true,
      collapsed: false,
      position: 'topright'
};

var overlays = {
  "Category One":{
    "Pizza": pizza,
    "Hamburger": hamburger
  },
  "Category Two": {
    "Pie": pie
  }
};


L.Control.Overlays = L.Control.extend({

onAdd: function (map) {
    var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'control-overlays');
        container.innerHTML = L.DomUtil.create('<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading" id="headingOne"><h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Heading Title</a></h4></div><div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"><div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div></div></div>', container);

    return container;
},

});

//L.control.groupedLayers(null, overlays, overlaysOptions).addTo(map);
var controlOverlays = new L.Control.Overlays(overlays, overlaysOptions).addTo(map);
```

Anyone know how to get the groupledlayers plugin inside the HTML div so I can work with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple bugs that need to be worked out before you get started. First, your filler text contains an apostrophe (in the word "haven't"), which needs to be escaped or it will invalidate everything after it. Second, you are using `L.DomUtil.create` incorrectly the second time you call it in your custom control function. If you want to add that HTML to the `container` div, you can simply use `container.innerHTML = '<div class="panel panel-default"> [etc. etc...]'`

Once you fix those things, you will see that both the grouped layer control and your custom control show up on the map. To get the one inside the other, I followed the trick that Jeff Mitzelfelt posted in [this Google Group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leaflet-js/rKMZX3PKFuI). Basically: create the layer control (assigned to a named `var`) and add it to the map; create another div (with an `id`) where you want to place the layer control; remove the container from the original control; then append the layer control to the new div using its `id`.

The following will place the grouped control inside the bootstrap panel:

```
L.Control.Overlays = L.Control.extend({
    onAdd: function (map) {
        var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'control-overlays');
            container.innerHTML = '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading" id="headingOne"><h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Heading Title</a></h4></div><div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body" id ="controlGoesHere">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven\'t heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div></div></div>';
        return container;
    }
});

var groupControl = L.control.groupedLayers(null, overlays, overlaysOptions).addTo(map);
var controlOverlays = new L.Control.Overlays(overlays, overlaysOptions).addTo(map);

groupControl._container.remove();
document.getElementById('controlGoesHere').appendChild(groupControl.onAdd(map));
```

The grouped control starts off in a strange state (the groups are turned off while all their items are turned on), but I assume this is just a matter of adjusting some options for the control.

**EDIT:** Here is an updated plunk with these changes:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6gtZIsUPVg0WCJ3WObNw?p=preview

Comment: When I run the updated plunk (in Chrome 77.0.3865.90 on Windows 10), the group control does not appear. Inspect says "index.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: L.control.groupedLayers is not a function". Before that, are 404s, indicating leaflet-groupedlayercontrol URLs are broken. I've tried replacing with updated URLs, e.g. "https://github.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol/blob/gh-pages/src/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.css", but that results in CORS errors, followed by the same error message.